# Error in effect.default....argument "offset" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, graph, regression

I'm looking to plot the effects for a TOBIT regression model at -1SD and +1SD using a bar graph. I would normally use a line graph, but my co-authors have asked for a bar graph instead. I have had some help identifying what I should do here, but I am getting an error that no one seems to be able to figure out.

Creating dataframe - this runs fine.

```
tobitforgraph <- survreg(Surv(S1, S2, type='right') ~ +(Var1centered)*Var2centered*Var3standardized,data=Datafilename, dist='gaussian', robust=TRUE))
```

Load effects library.

```
library(effects)
```

Extract values for plotting (the values coming from here are then supposed to be used to plot as normal in Excel, although there may be a way to do it in R; regardless, this is where I am getting an error).

```
print((intplot<-as.data.frame(ef< Effect(c("Var1centered","Var3standardized"),mod=tobitforgraph,xlevels=list(Var1centered=c(-.4987531,.5012469),Var3standardized=c(-1.0,1.0), data=subset(Datafilename, Var4==-0.5025))))))
```

Error that comes from this value extraction:

```
Error in Effect.default(c("Var1centered", "Var3standardized"), mod = tobitforgraph,  : 
  argument "offset" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The `print` call with an attribution (intplot <- ) is a bit odd. Could you `dput(tobitforgraph)` and post the result here, so it'd be reproducible?

Comment: @csgroen Thank you for the welcome and for the response! I've run it and have the data, although it's too long to fit in a comment here. I'll see if there's a way to post that condensed, or else will post in multiple comments.

Comment: Maybe `dput(head(tobitforgraph))`

Comment: That's better, although still 10,000 characters over limit (yikes!).

Comment: How about `dput(head(Datafilename))`?

Comment: That one is the longest, unfortunately (50,000 characters over). Should I just post multiple comments from the dput(head(tobitforgraph)) run? It would unfortunately be about 20 comments, with the limit of about 500 characters. Or, if there's a way to e-mail it or some other method of transferring, I could certainly do that! Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Ok, try making a smaller version of your `Datafilename`, with only the variables needed to generate the survival regression model. Something like: `data <- Datafilename[,c("S1", "S2", "Var1centered", "Var2centered", "Var3standardized")]`. Then `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: @csgroen OK I created a new data file with only those variables and ran it again but it's still over by about 9500 characters. There are 400 participants, so maybe that's why it's so large.

Comment: Yes, maybe limit to only about 10 to 20 patients. Then you'll have a 'toy' example, but it should be reproducible.

Comment: Geeze, even with only 10, it's still over by about 2000 characters. Should I post the result in 4-5 comments?

Comment: Edit your answer and see if you can post it there

Comment: The character limit is the same.

Comment: Will post multiple. Here is the first:  structure(list(coefficients = structure(c(717.985383694802, -1017.70586702707, 
-540.906276301055, 18.4460803702806, 1039.55093979238, 255.440659093219, 
-639.798477871299, 1569.06090511838), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"Var1centered", "Var2centered", "Var3standardized", "Var1centered:Var2centered", 
"Var1centered:Var3standardized", "Var2centered:Var3standardized", 
"Var1centered:Var2centered:Var3standardized")), icoef = structure(c(439.444243668647, 
5.31686317855074), .Names = c("Intercept", "Log(scale)")), var = structure(c(6324.72998818462,

Comment: -13539.8538188548, -28430.0398272901, 10785.9889303455, 81173.5294480618, 
-28125.345654268, -4171.38752901993, 0, 4.05499803017139, -13539.8538188548, 
43177.2242705489, 87200.7228420943, -31757.0069711659, -246084.207317039, 
88821.6467316226, 7599.7193047675, 0, 3.89235151607518, -28430.0398272901, 
87200.7228420943, 199404.807929236, -72417.1096167837, -567599.123152373, 
205605.47087128, 8763.87330858642, 0, 13.289965568403, 10785.9889303455, 
-31757.0069711659, -72417.1096167837, 27312.8412341334, 208869.271467689, 
-74896.8616945772, -2579.29811547566, 0, -3.9119994502683,

Comment: 81173.5294480618, 
-246084.207317039, -567599.123152373, 208869.271467689, 1668683.91183787, 
-604762.822683505, -15827.3966477596, 0, -54.7375710625509, -28125.345654268, 
88821.6467316226, 205605.47087128, -74896.8616945772, -604762.822683505, 
224541.991030357, 122.927345271523, 0, 19.6430181853462, -4171.38752901993, 
7599.7193047675, 8763.87330858642, -2579.29811547566, -15827.3966477596, 
122.927345271523, 12074.487688487, 0, -4.46861273349958, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.05499803017139, 3.89235151607518, 13.289965568403, 
-3.9119994502683,

Comment: -54.7375710625509, 19.6430181853462, -4.46861273349958, 
0, 0.0513061433648101), .Dim = c(9L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
"Var1centered", "Var2centered", "Var3standardized", "Var1centered:Var2centered", 
"Var1centered:Var3standardized", "Var2centered:Var3standardized", 
"Var1centered:Var2centered:Var3standardized", "Log(scale)"), 
    c("(Intercept)", "Var1centered", "Var2centered", "Var3standardized", 
    "Var1centered:Var2centered", "Var1centered:Var3standardized", 
    "Var2centered:Var3standardized", "Var1centered:Var2centered:Var3standardized", 
    "Log(scale)"))),

Comment: loglik = c(-91.3024966794904, -84.3728653491042
), iter = 11L, linear.predictors = c(569.222318619726, 440.71635277638, 
313.688740543165, 447.126137699772, 439.445350824208, 182.708816349697, 
398.975386553182, 356.231305448684, 436.120011739373, 595.385700547756, 
345.954981737702, 568.46612783809, 528.832223320689, 336.471490800705, 
304.248275802786, 1411.86524723979, 256.71814482228, 323.450609572554, 
316.211869446047, 311.618242299137, 1074.85667784783, 308.001915244551, 
1888.20461916381, 2504.09157230196, 367.477396760468, 318.969900020733, 
1599.84664491259, 383.114591017328,

Comment: 556.447524353034)), .Names = c("coefficients", 
"icoef", "var", "loglik", "iter", "linear.predictors"))    #This is the last line! @csgroen